# Running Hyperopt in Freqtrade and getting crazy results

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency, hyperopt

I ran hyperopt for 5000 iterations and got the following results:

2022-01-10 19:38:31,370 - freqtrade.optimize.hyperopt - INFO - Best result:

1101 trades. Avg profit  0.23%. Total profit  25.48064438 BTC (254.5519Σ%). Avg duration 888.1 mins.

with values:

{   'roi_p1': 0.011364434095803464,

```
'roi_p2': 0.04123147845715937,

'roi_p3': 0.10554480985209454,

'roi_t1': 105,

'roi_t2': 47,

'roi_t3': 30,

'rsi-enabled': True,

'rsi-value': 9,

'sell-rsi-enabled': True,

'sell-rsi-value': 94,

'sell-trigger': 'sell-bb_middle1',

'stoploss': -0.42267640639979365,

'trigger': 'bb_lower2'}
```

2022-01-10 19:38:31,371 - freqtrade.optimize.hyperopt - INFO - ROI table:

{   0: 0.15814072240505736,

```
30: 0.05259591255296283,

77: 0.011364434095803464,

182: 0}
```

Result for strategy BBRSI

================================================== BACKTESTING REPORT =================================================

| pair      |   buy count |   avg profit % |   cum profit % |   total profit BTC | avg duration    |   profit |   loss |

|:----------|------------:|---------------:|---------------:|-------------------:|:----------------|---------:|-------:|

| ETH/BTC   |          11 |          -1.30 |         -14.26 |        -1.42732928 | 3 days, 4:55:00 |        0 |      1 |

| LUNA/BTC  |          17 |           0.60 |          10.22 |         1.02279906 | 15:46:00        |        9 |      0 |

| SAND/BTC  |          37 |           0.30 |          11.24 |         1.12513532 | 6:16:00         |       14 |      1 |

| MATIC/BTC |          24 |           0.47 |          11.35 |         1.13644340 | 12:20:00        |       10 |      0 |

| ADA/BTC   |          24 |           0.24 |           5.68 |         0.56822170 | 21:05:00        |        5 |      0 |

| BNB/BTC   |          11 |          -1.09 |         -11.96 |        -1.19716109 | 3 days, 0:44:00 |        2 |      1 |

| XRP/BTC   |          20 |          -0.39 |          -7.71 |        -0.77191523 | 1 day, 5:48:00  |        1 |      1 |

| DOT/BTC   |           9 |           0.50 |           4.54 |         0.45457736 | 4 days, 1:13:00 |        4 |      0 |

| SOL/BTC   |          19 |          -0.38 |          -7.16 |        -0.71688463 | 22:47:00        |        3 |      1 |

| MANA/BTC  |          29 |           0.38 |          11.16 |         1.11753320 | 10:25:00        |        9 |      1 |

| AVAX/BTC  |          27 |           0.30 |           8.15 |         0.81561432 | 16:36:00        |       11 |      1 |

| GALA/BTC  |          26 |          -0.52 |         -13.45 |        -1.34594702 | 15:48:00        |        9 |      1 |

| LINK/BTC  |          21 |           0.27 |           5.68 |         0.56822170 | 1 day, 0:06:00  |        5 |      0 |

| TOTAL     |         275 |           0.05 |          13.48 |         1.34930881 | 23:42:00        |       82 |      8 |

================================================== SELL REASON STATS ==================================================

| Sell Reason   |   Count |

|:--------------|--------:|

| roi           |     267 |

| force_sell    |       8 |

=============================================== LEFT OPEN TRADES REPORT ===============================================

| pair     |   buy count |   avg profit % |   cum profit % |   total profit BTC | avg duration      |   profit |   loss |

|:---------|------------:|---------------:|---------------:|-------------------:|:------------------|---------:|-------:|

| ETH/BTC  |           1 |         -14.26 |         -14.26 |        -1.42732928 | 32 days, 4:00:00  |        0 |      1 |

| SAND/BTC |           1 |          -4.65 |          -4.65 |        -0.46588544 | 17:00:00          |        0 |      1 |

| BNB/BTC  |           1 |         -14.23 |         -14.23 |        -1.42444977 | 31 days, 13:00:00 |        0 |      1 |

| XRP/BTC  |           1 |          -8.85 |          -8.85 |        -0.88555957 | 18 days, 4:00:00  |        0 |      1 |

| SOL/BTC  |           1 |         -10.57 |         -10.57 |        -1.05781765 | 5 days, 14:00:00  |        0 |      1 |

| MANA/BTC |           1 |          -3.17 |          -3.17 |        -0.31758065 | 17:00:00          |        0 |      1 |

| AVAX/BTC |           1 |         -12.58 |         -12.58 |        -1.25910300 | 7 days, 9:00:00   |        0 |      1 |

| GALA/BTC |           1 |         -23.66 |         -23.66 |        -2.36874608 | 7 days, 12:00:00  |        0 |      1 |

| TOTAL    |           8 |         -11.50 |         -91.97 |        -9.20647144 | 12 days, 23:15:00 |        0 |      8 |

Have accurately followed the tutorial. Don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting one of the OHLC columns (with heikin ashi for example) or you have unrealistic tight trailing stoploss.

Read this fine article: https://brookmiles.github.io/freqtrade-stuff/2021/04/12/backtesting-traps/